# Xamarin right click event

Tags: xamarin, mouseevent, right-click

Is there any way to detect a right click event from a mouse when using Xamarin for a UWP app? There does not seem to be any way to access mouse events except as they simulate touch events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is just a pure UWP app there is a `UIElement.PointerPressed` Event you can subscribe to.

```
void Target_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.Pointer ptr = e.Pointer;

    if (ptr.PointerDeviceType == Windows.Devices.Input.PointerDeviceType.Mouse)
    {
        Windows.UI.Input.PointerPoint ptrPt = e.GetCurrentPoint(Target);

        if (ptrPt.Properties.IsRightButtonPressed)
        {
            // Do something
        }

        // Prevent most handlers along the event route from handling the same event again.
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Check out the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.pointerpressed) for more info.

Comment: This looks quite promising, thanks for the response. Now let's say that I have a Xamarin control (e.g. Xamarin.Forms.Grid), how do I get the underlying UIElement for that control in the case where it is a UWP app. Note, I am not looking for a cross platform solution, only one that will works with UWP apps.

Comment: The easiest way might be to use the native control directly in [Xaml/C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/native-views/), especially if this is intended only as a UWP Forms app. It's that or you'll have to create your own custom renderer for that specific control(s).

Comment: The app is cross platform, but when the user is using the Windows version, I want to add some mouse functionality that would not be available on the other platforms. I will look into the custom renderer. Thanks again.

Comment: Well that was a lot of hoops to jump through just to be able to tell if the user clicked with the right mouse button but it works. Thanks for your help.